# How to set a jQuery code to auto scroll to id from table?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I return to this page post updating or working on a specific id, which works well. The page consists of a table that has a list of properties, each property has a unique id. What I am looking to achieve is that after the post-back method I should scroll back to the same ID which I just finished working on. This way I know where I ended and can continue working on the next property. I used the jQuery function, but it is not working for me.

I am using ASP.NET MVC, I store id in ViewBag and have added it as an id to the td in the table. See the below code.

Action postback Method

```
public ActionResult MyPendingTask(string area, string subarea)
{
    var subArea = subarea;
    var parentArea = area;

    int id = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["ID"]);

    ViewBag.PropID = id;

    // var uName = User.Identity.Name;
    Property prop = db.Properties.Where(x => x.AreaSlug == area && x.SubAreaSlug == subarea).FirstOrDefault();
    var aname = prop.AreaName;
    var sname = prop.SubArea;

    ViewBag.AreaName = aname;
    ViewBag.SubAname = sname;

    var result = db.Properties
                   .Where(x => x.AreaSlug == area && x.SubAreaSlug == subarea)
                   .ToArray().ToList()
                   .OrderBy(x => x.IsPropertyActive != null);

    return View(result);
}
```

View:

```
<div class="card-body" id="scrollDiv">
    <table id="dataTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Prop ID</th>
                <th>Owner Name</th>
                <th>Owner Mobile #</th>
                <th>Owner Email</th>
                <th>Is Prop Active?</th>
                <th>Area</th>
                <th>Sub Area</th>
                <th><p><input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search.." class="form-control"></p>No Of BRoom</th>
                <th>Unit Number</th>
                <th>Unit Type</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td id="@ViewBag.PropID">@item.PropId</td>
                <td>@item.OwnerName</td>
                <td>@item.OwnerMobNumber</td>
                <td>@item.OwnerEmail</td>
                <td>@item.IsPropertyActive</td>
                <td>@item.AreaName</td>
                <td>@item.SubArea</td>
                <td><span>@item.NoOfBRoom</span></td>
                <td>@item.UnitNumber</td>
                <td>@item.UnitType</td>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
                    <a href="/CoOrdinator/ReviewProperty/@item.PropId" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Review</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

jQuery ScrollTo Top function

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var id = parseInt(@ViewBag.PropID);

    var container = $('div#scrollDiv'),
    scrollTo = $('td#'+id);

    container.animate({
                scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
    });
```

Thank you

Comment: `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#anyElement').offset().top}, 'slow');`

This code should work.

Comment: Thank yo for fast reply. Tried this but no success. var id = parseInt(@ViewBag.PropID);


            $('html, tbody').animate({ scrollTop: $('#' + id).offset().top }, 'slow');

Comment: verify `id` and also change `tbody` to `body`

Comment: I did verify the id and stored it in var, also added alert fnction to verify the id and it shows the correct id. But, it does not  auto scroll to id. var id = parseInt(@ViewBag.PropID); var scrollTo = '#' + id; alert(scrollTo);

            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top }, 'slow');

Comment: `var scrollTo = $('#' + id); alert(scrollTo);`